# _ServerClick event and Response.Redirect: wrong redirection

Tags: vb.net, htmlcontrols, system.web.ui.webcontrols

Perhaps this question is a bit too general, but I'll try to narrow it down by explaining my scenario.

I have a login page, with an html input button:

```
<input runat="server" id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login"></input>
```

The button triggers the btnLogin_ServerClick event which runs a validation routine.

If the user is validated the following happens:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/myPage.aspx")
```

This is all good in development environment.

However, after I deployed my application, the validated user would still be redirected to the localhost URL, instead of the application URL corresponding to the root directory.

After lots of trials and errors, I've fixed the issue by changing the button to a webcontrol namespace button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login"/>
```

This triggers a Click event in the code behind.

The routine is exactly the same as in the development environment, but the user is now redirected to the appropriate URL.

So, could anyone explain why the ServerClick event was making Response.Redirect "behave" differently?